# Firebase Cloud Functions not logging, do not seem to be deploying

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase Cloud Functions have not been logging since approx. 4pm this afternoon. They also do not seem to be deploying properly, but it's hard to tell with no logs.

Missing logs on the website, and also when running the cli with "firebase functions:log"

Anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly if you think there is an outage in service.  https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/

Comment: If it's something on your side, you'll have to show us a bit more that allows us to help you troubleshoot. Have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you suspect it's something on the Google/Firebase side, this is not the place to ask for updates. Have a look at the [Firebase status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/) or [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I don't think it's something on their side. It's happening to me too on a project and environment that was previously working before today.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yeah, I can confirm that there is either an outage or an extreme coincidence. Project is working on all endpoints (async and non-async) but console debugging is currently impossible.

Comment: Logs for some functions that ran today are showing up in the console for me. And I haven't seen other reports yet, so definitely report to support. They're always more likely to see trend.

Comment: I can confirm this is a real problem. We are also not getting any logs on firebase.

Comment: I received GCP email ask me to update my firebase cloud function to node8. After update it show no more log, however my function is actually running after I manually check my database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm also using node 8, maybe that's the problem? I'll reach out to support soon when I have a free minute. thanks