# Why is cloud function executed on deployment?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

When I edit my index.js file and run `firebase deploy --only functions`.

I get logs like this:

`Function execution started.`
`Function execution took 717 ms. Finished with status code: 200`

but not in even proportions. I.e there are more logs saying function execution took x ms, than there are messages saying function execution started.

I also receive multiple logs of the following format:

https://justpaste.it/4moy4

and

https://justpaste.it/98urv

(also in uneven proportions).

Please can someone explain what these messages mean?

Why is my https function executing on deployment if I am not calling it from the client?

Why are there more finished executing messages than started executing messages?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't link to the data you want to show.  Copy it into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read.

Comment: Good question. I always guess that for being sure that the init was OK (start, init all the global variable, and stop. If there is exception, the deployment is considered as a failure)

Comment: Thanks guillaume! I assumed it may be something like this, but not quite sure why the seemingly linked logs don't appear in the same quantities! Hopefully someone knows and can elaborate  :)

Comment: can you update your question with code what you are trying.

Comment: This isn't specific to any one code snippet. It occurs any time I deploy my index.js file and not necessarily one log for each function, so there's not much point in supplying an arbitrary section of the code, due to the random nature of the logs.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756167/firebase-cloud-functions-not-logging-do-not-seem-to-be-deploying